# From DWG to Shapefile: How to extract the channels length of water courses?

Tags: shapefile, convert, watershed, cad, dwg

I have a DWG file with the drainage system of a small town. I need to open it on ArcGIS and get the total length of the channels that are part of one of the watersheds in the city.

When I convert the DWG to shapefiles, the attribute table on ArcGIS does not show the length of each channel?

I am doing anything wrong? What is the correct way to convert a DWG file to shapefile and be able to also export the geometric features of the watershed?

Comment: Not all CAD attributes are transferred over, depending on CAD file type/version.  Have you tried to [Calculate Geometry](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/tables/calculating-area-length-and-other-geometric-properties.htm)?

Comment: Yes, I did with other watersheds that were sent to me in shapefile. Now I have a DWG file, but the attribute table does not have any information when I export DWG to SHP, which does not allow me to calculate geometry.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have imported your data and that your are not just viewing the DWG native file (they can't be edited). To do CAD data import, see here some hints : https://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2010/05/24/importing-cad-data-in-arcgis-10-0/

The length needs to be added to the attribute table within Arcgis, unless you have imported your data in a geodatabase (then it will automatically be added). To do that, you can follow instructions in the help files :

- http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/tables/calculating-area-length-and-other-geometric-properties.htm
- Or a video here : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HvKCXbhmnU0